Сервер nginx не может получить доступ к файлу
В centOS, запущенной в виртуальной машине, в директории лежат два файла:

Файл iii.html сервер nginx отдает без ошибок. На файле iii2.html возвращается 403 Forbidden.
В логах nginx:

Содержимое файлов одинаковое- <h1>TEST</h1>.
Конфигурация сервиса nginx:

Почему при одинаковом наборе прав доступа для двух одинаковых файлов, лежащих в одной и той же директории, в одном случае все ок (файл iii.html), а в другом- нет прав (файл iii2.html)?

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
